# Query based on day-of-week/time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm on SQL Server 2014. I have a table with columns like this:

| id (int, PK, identity) | effectiveDate (datetime) | expirationDate (datetime) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-06 18:00:00.000 | 2022-07-06 23:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2022-07-08 22:00:00.000 | 2022-07-09 02:00:00.000 |

I need to select rows where the current date/time (`GETDATE()`) lands within the day-of-week/time range represented by these datetimes, beginning on the `effectiveDate`. So think of row 1 as the range `Wednesday 18:00 -> Wednesday 23:00` and row 2 as `Friday 22:00 -> Saturday 02:00`. (Keep in mind the day-of-week/time range can span multiple days, as in the 2nd row.)

Examples:

- `GETDATE()` = `2022-07-06 19:30:00.000` (i.e Wednesday at 19:30)

  - Selects row 1
- `GETDATE()` = `2022-07-30 01:00:00.000` (i.e. Saturday at 01:00)

  - Selects row 2
- `GETDATE()` = `2022-06-30 19:00:00.000` (i.e. Wednesday at 19:00 which matches row 1 on the day-of-week/time range, but is before the effective date)

  - Selects nothing

I'm not quite sure how to attack this. Maybe we could date adjust each row's `effectiveDate` and `expirationDate` as many weeks forward as needed to place the `effectiveDate` before `GETDATE()` (assuming the `effectiveDate <= GETDATE()`). Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to find all rows `WHERE GETDATE() >= effectiveDate AND GETDATE() < expirationDate`
Am I missing something from your question?

Comment: Yes. The issue is these dates represent a recurring, weekly event, not just the 1 event between the effective and expiration dates. If you just match the effective/expiration dates, you'll only match the 1st week and miss every week after that. Check out the 2nd example above. 2022-07-30 is not in row 2's date range. But it's within the same day-of-week/time range as row 2, which is why it should be selected.

Comment: Will the range ever be more than one week?  Friday to a Monday two weeks later, for example.  Would this be a Fri to Mon or Mon to Fri?  Some odd thing dealing with the a defined work week?

Comment: Or perhaps if the range is more than one week, all days are included?

Comment: The range must be less than 1 week. The effective/expiration date can at most be 6 days 23 hours and 30 minutes apart (30 minutes shy of a week). In practice, they'll likely be only a few hours apart.

Answer (score 0):

The DATEPART with weekday is the key to checking the weekday range.  There are two cases.  For example, Mon to Wed is different than Wed to Mon.  Mon to Wed is easy with a test of Mon<=day<= Wed.  For Wed to Mon, it becomes day < Mon or day > Wed.  However, this is the same as NOT Mon<=day<=Wed.  The query might not be exactly what you need, but should be a good start.

```
with TestData as (
    select * 
    from (
        values 
            (1, CAST('2022-07-06 18:00:00.000' as datetime), CAST('2022-07-06 23:00:00.000' as datetime)),
            (2, CAST('2022-07-08 22:00:00.000' as datetime), CAST('2022-07-09 02:00:00.000' as datetime)),
            (3, CAST('2022-07-09 22:00:00.000' as datetime), CAST('2022-07-11 10:00:00.000' as datetime))
    ) t (id, effectiveDate, expirationDate)
), TestSamples as (
    select * 
    from (
        values 
            (CAST('2022-07-06 19:30:00.000' as datetime)),
            (CAST('2022-07-30 01:00:00.000' as datetime)),
            (CAST('2022-07-31 01:00:00.000' as datetime)),
            (CAST('2022-06-30 19:00:00.000' as datetime)),
            (CAST('2022-08-04 19:00:00.000' as datetime))
    ) t (testDate)
), WeekDayRange as (
    select id, effectiveDate, expirationDate, 
        datename(weekday, effectiveDate) as WDNAME1, datename(weekday, expirationDate) as WDNAME2, 
        datepart(weekday, effectiveDate) as WD1, datepart(weekday, expirationDate) as WD2
    from TestData
) select t.testDate, datename(weekday, t.testDate) as [WDNAME], datepart(weekday, t.testDate) as [WD], r.*
from  TestSamples t
left join WeekDayRange r
on (r.WD1 <= r.WD2 and datepart(weekday, t.testDate) BETWEEN r.WD1 and r.WD2)
    or (r.WD1 > r.WD2 and not datepart(weekday, t.testDate) BETWEEN r.WD2 and r.WD1)
where t.testDate > r.effectiveDate
```

```
testDate                WDNAME    WD          id          effectiveDate           expirationDate          WDNAME1   WDNAME2   WD1         WD2
----------------------- --------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- --------- --------- ----------- -----------
2022-07-06 19:30:00.000 Wednesday 4           1           2022-07-06 18:00:00.000 2022-07-06 23:00:00.000 Wednesday Wednesday 4           4
2022-07-30 01:00:00.000 Saturday  7           2           2022-07-08 22:00:00.000 2022-07-09 02:00:00.000 Friday    Saturday  6           7
2022-07-31 01:00:00.000 Sunday    1           3           2022-07-09 22:00:00.000 2022-07-11 10:00:00.000 Saturday  Monday    7           2
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a clever solution. Thank you for taking the time to help! I just added another solution I think is working based on my tests. Check it out and let me know if you can spot any issues if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this working with a bit of math:

```
DECLARE @myGetDate DATETIME;
SET @myGetDate = '2022-07-30 01:00:00.000';

WITH AdjustedWeeklyDates AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(day, effectiveDate, @myGetDate) / 7, effectiveDate) AS adjustedEffectiveDate,
        DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(day, effectiveDate, @myGetDate) / 7, expirationDate) AS adjustedExpirationDate
    FROM
        dbo.myTable
    WHERE
        effectiveDate <= @myGetDate
)
SELECT
    mt.ID, mt.effectiveDate, mt.expirationDate, awd.adjustedEffectiveDate, awd.adjustedExpirationDate
FROM dbo.myTable mt
    INNER JOIN AdjustedWeeklyDates awd ON mt.ID = awd.ID
WHERE 
    awd.adjustedEffectiveDate <= @myGetDate
    AND awd.adjustedExpirationDate > @myGetDate
```

To explain:

- `DATEDIFF(day, effectiveDate, @myGetDate)` returns the number of days between the `effectiveDate` and the current date. So for example, say it was 20 days ago.
- `/ 7` gets the number of weeks as an int, since the `DATEDIFF` returns an int. This also results in the floor of the quotient. So, with our example 20 days / 7, the quotient is about 2.86, but this will result in an even 2
- `DATEADD` adds the number of weeks to bring us up to or before the current date/time. We add the same number of weeks to the expiration date, resulting in the same range as the original effective/expiration dates, which may or may not extend around the current date.
- Finally the check for `effectiveDate <= @myGetDate` guarantees the current date is after or equal to the effective date.